# Send message to iMessage group using javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is it possible to send messages to an iMessage group using javascript?
I've found solutions using applescript but none using javascript/node

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at this Node package https://www.npmjs.com/package/osa-imessage. It looks easy to use and exactly what you need.

```
const imessage = require('osa-imessage');
imessage.send('chat000000000000000000', 'Hello everyone!');
```